# MVC: Use views, constants, or model properties?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, constants

Lets say that in my mvc application, I have a model that has many different types. There's one db table but a bunch of subclasses that express slightly varied behavior.

On the page, sometimes I want to show the list of all these model types, and sometimes (when one is currently active) show the details of that one. The details shown are rather small, a few words at most, so I'm having trouble deciding where to put them.

**Option 1 (the old pre-refactoring way)**: In an array with properties for each of the detail fields. The benefit is I can iterate through all the possible types. With classes, there's nothing to iterate through. I'd prefer to get rid of this array.

**Option 2:** In the model as properties. The views would access these properties based on the currently active type, but I still have nothing to iterate through and show all types. I may have to show them all explicitly (only 9 of them, not terrible.)

**Option 3:** In separate views, literally written. I would have 9 different views but this lets them be slightly different. The layout of each type could vary.

For some detail, this is for a game and the model is a bunch of actions your character can do. They behave similarly but affect different stats in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with something like this?

```
public interface ICharacter {
 IEnumerable<ICharacterAction> Actions {get;set;}
}

public interface ICharacterAction {
 string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Because this question is tagged with "PHP", not with "C#"